# Certbot Python Augeas dependency

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services

Trying to spin up a simple LAMP service with AWS and Certbot SSL. Followed all the directions but my when I run the certbot-auto I'm given the following error:

```
The apache plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
The error was: NoInstallationError('Problem in Augeas installation',)
```

My attempts to install python-augeas via:
`pip3 install python-augeas`

result:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-27aroyjq/python-augeas/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-27aroyjq/python-augeas/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-27aroyjq/python-augeas/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-27aroyjq/python-augeas/
    Complete output (31 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-27aroyjq/python-augeas/setup.py", line 43, in <module>
        test_suite="test.test_augeas",
      File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 448, in __init__
        k: v for k, v in attrs.items()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 281, in __init__
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 740, in finalize_options
        ep.load()(self)
      File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 747, in _finalize_setup_keywords
        ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-27aroyjq/python-augeas/.eggs/cffi-1.14.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 217, in cffi_modules
        add_cffi_module(dist, cffi_module)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-27aroyjq/python-augeas/.eggs/cffi-1.14.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 49, in add_cffi_module
        execfile(build_file_name, mod_vars)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-27aroyjq/python-augeas/.eggs/cffi-1.14.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 25, in execfile
        exec(code, glob, glob)
      File "augeas/ffi.py", line 47, in <module>
        lib = ffi.dlopen("augeas")
      File "/tmp/pip-install-27aroyjq/python-augeas/.eggs/cffi-1.14.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/cffi/api.py", line 150, in dlopen
        lib, function_cache = _make_ffi_library(self, name, flags)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-27aroyjq/python-augeas/.eggs/cffi-1.14.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/cffi/api.py", line 832, in _make_ffi_library
        backendlib = _load_backend_lib(backend, libname, flags)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-27aroyjq/python-augeas/.eggs/cffi-1.14.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/cffi/api.py", line 827, in _load_backend_lib
        raise OSError(msg)
    OSError: ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'augeas'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Well ... does `libaugeas` exist on your system? Ideally with the header files required to build anything using it?

Comment: Please, stop doing that. AWS provides ACM service and SSL certificates for free

Answer (score 3):

```
$ yum install augeas
$ python3 -m pip install certbot
```

This fixed the problem on a AWS Linux 2 instance.
If you use a load balancer then you can use the AWS ACM service.
If not, I found Certbot works really well.

Thanks tink for pointing me the right direction.